# removing covariates from a linear mixed model using update

Tags: r, loops, lapply, lme4

I'm newish to R.  I have a linear mixed model with several predictors and I want to test the significance of each of them. I know that I could use lmerTest but my co-authors want me to do a likelihood ratio test for each predictor instead. I would like to use the update function to get a series of submodels that omit each predictor in turn.  I tried the following

```
data(mtcars)

h=lmer(mpg ~ 1 + cyl + disp + hp + drat + (1|carb), data=mtcars)

predvars=c("cyl","disp","hp","drat")
for (i in predvars){
  modelform=update(as.formula(paste0("h, . ~ . -",i)))
  print(summary(modelform))
 }
```

I got the following error

Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  :1:2: unexpected ','
1: h,
     ^

I also tried using lapply

```
Fits=lapply(predvars, function(x) {update(h, .~.-i, list(i=as.name(x)))})
names(Fits)=predvars
```

which doesn't actually update the model, it just refits the full model i times. What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt generates an error because you put `h` inside `as.formula`. Do:

```
  modelform <- update(h, as.formula(paste0(". ~ . -",i)))
```

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks much.

Comment: @Carol Glad to help. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), otherwise it is considered as unanswered by SO.